# snowflake - can we host it in Private cloud?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

"Snowflake cannot be run on private cloud infrastructures (on-premises or hosted) " why is this so ? and what does it take to host it on private cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because only Snowflake decides how to offer their software, and they decided no on-prem or hosted.  There is no way to work past that.

Answer (score 0):

Arun, you can not host Snowflake on a private cloud but you can ask for a private deployment dedicated you:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/intro-editions.html#virtual-private-snowflake-vps

By the way, it can not be deployed on-premises because the Snowflake is build for Cloud, and it depends on some cloud components.

Comment: And I am sure Snowflake would love to hear feedback on what requirements you may have that their current offerings do not achieve.  A Snowflake VPS, for example, offers a lot of great security features and advantages.